# carousel inside Bootstrap modal in half column

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

how can I add the carousel to modal in half column.

I use [Bootstrap modal carousel](https://noreiller.github.io/bootstrap-modal-carousel/index.html) a JavaScript and CSS extensions to Twitter Boostrap. But I need to make carousel in half column of the modal body. [image: like this]

like this, I see the [documentation](https://noreiller.github.io/bootstrap-modal-carousel/modal-carousel.html) of bootstrap model carousel to add carousel to the modal is just add `data-local="#myCarousel"` it's going to make carousel full screen on modal body. But I need to make carousel to fit my right column.

```
<div class="modal fade modal-fullscreen force-fullscreen" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
     <!-- Another column -->
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
     <!-- #MyCarousel here -->
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
   </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
 </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

How can  I configure my carousel modal bootstrap to adding carousel in my second column?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the carousel structure in the half column if you just want to have a fullscreen modal with half of if being carousel.

Here is the fiddle for that [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/qn7911ef/)

If you want to take the carousel from the page and insert it into the modal with it being half of the modal you can do the following which will probably be better as the modal will not run in the background continuously:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" id="myModal">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body row">
    <div class="left-section"></div>
    <div class="right-section"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
   </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
 </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<button id="load-modal" class="btn btn-primary">Toggle Modal</button>



    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x440/cccccc/ffffff">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

         <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x440/999999/cccccc">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x440/dddddd/333333">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

      </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div><!-- End Carousel -->
```

Then the CSS:

```
#myModal .modal-dialog{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#myModal .modal-content{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
#myModal .modal-footer{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.left-section{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.right-section{
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

And the Jquery:

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    target.removeData('bs.modal')
    .find(".right-section").html('');
});
$( document ).on( "click", "#load-modal", function(e) {
    var content = $('#myCarousel').clone(true);
    $("#myModal .right-section").html(content);
    $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

Here is a fiddle for that [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/em1dz3p8/)

This will clone the carousel from the page and then insert it into the left section.  Then when the modal closes it will remove it from the right section.

Comment: So I still need use carousel bootstrap modal extension for that ? Or I need to use standard carousel for js and css file?

Comment: R u just trying to have a fullscreen modal?  Is that all your trying to do or do you want to use the plugin for something else?  If you just want a fullscreen modal you can do that with just bootstrap's css and javascript and then add a little css to make the modal fullscreen.  Here is a fiddle of a fullscreen modal with the carousel in it.  https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/zye9qraj/

Comment: If you want the modal footer to be on the bottom you can use this fiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/qn7911ef/ .  Otherwise I have tested it with the plugin found here https://github.com/noreiller/bootstrap-modal-carousel and it works with that as well just insert the bootstrap carousel in the right column of the modal and it should work just fine.  But if you just want a fullscreen modal and don't want the plugin for anything else there is probably no reason to use the plugin just use the example in the fiddle above.

Comment: because my button close not working and sometimes the carousel-fit not working for size at both browser chrome and firefox. Ok thanks for your suggest I will try a sec

Comment: Ok thanks for your CSS. I'm not use carousel bootstrap modal extension and working like charm.

Comment: I got to thinking and if you are going to have the same carousel on the page it would probably be better to pull it from the page and insert it into the modal and then remove it when the modal closes so it is not running in the background the whole time.  So I have edited my answer with some code to do that with.  You will need to use a bit of jquery but it will be much more efficient this way.